# Why do JavaFX charts shrink based on the Axis?

Tags: java, javafx

Suppose I have a simple ScatterChart example, as posted here

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series;

public class AutoAlignment extends Application {

        private void init(Stage primaryStage) {

            Group root = new Group();
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
            NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(58.7,59.35,0.1);
            xAxis.setTickLabelRotation( 360 );
            xAxis.setLabel( "Time" );
            yAxis.setLabel( "Price" );

            Series test = new ScatterChart.Series("Series 1", FXCollections.<ScatterChart.Data>observableArrayList());
            test.getData().addAll(                new XYChart.Data("11:44",59.23),
                    new XYChart.Data("11:45",59.28),
                    new XYChart.Data("11:46",59.23),
                    new XYChart.Data("11:47",59.2),
                    new XYChart.Data("11:48",59.14),
                    new XYChart.Data("11:49",59.15),
                    new XYChart.Data("11:50",59.19),
                    new XYChart.Data("11:51",59.15),
                    new XYChart.Data("11:52",59.13),
                    new XYChart.Data("11:53",59.2),
                    new XYChart.Data("11:54",59.15),
                    new XYChart.Data("11:55",59.16));

            ObservableList<XYChart.Series> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(test); 
            ScatterChart chart = new ScatterChart(xAxis, yAxis, data);
            root.getChildren().add(chart);
        }

        @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            init(primaryStage);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
    }
```

Using a small yAxis range, the graph shrinks and produces a large white space gap between the yAxis label and the actual chart.

If I remove the yAxis parameters and just do

```
NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
```

then the graph comes out normal. What causes the graph to shrink this way, and how can I prevent this? I want the Axis to be customized, but also not shrunk like the first case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the axis is leaving lots of space for labels that might include a large number of decimal places.

Adding a `tickLabelFormatter` seems to fix the problem:

```
        yAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Number>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Number object) {
                return String.format("%.1f", object.doubleValue());
            }

            @Override
            public Number fromString(String string) {
                return new Double(string);
            }

        });
```

Comment: The axis does seem to automatically adjust space for potentially long label, didn't think of that before. Great solution.